# Why language.Matcher returns such strange result?

Tags: go, http-accept-language

I am implementing a multilang web service based on `Accept-Language` header. I use next code for parsing header and getting the requested language:

```
var matcher = language.NewMatcher([]language.Tag{
    language.English,
    language.Russian,
})
header:="ru, RUS, ru-RU, ru-ru"
tags, q, err := language.ParseAcceptLanguage(header)
for key, tag := range tags {
        matched, _, c := matcher.Match(tag)
        fmt.Printf("%s=>%f Matched as: %s (confidence: %s)\n", tag, q[key], matched, c)
    }
```

And results I get is

```
ru=>1.000000 Matched as: ru (confidence: Exact)
ru=>1.000000 Matched as: ru (confidence: Exact)
ru-RU=>1.000000 Matched as: ru-u-rg-ruzzzz (confidence: Exact)
ru-RU=>1.000000 Matched as: ru-u-rg-ruzzzz (confidence: Exact)
```

Why is 'ru-RU' matched as strange tag 'ru-u-rg-ruzzzz'? How can I match 'ru-Ru' as 'ru'?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add "ru-RU" when you create your matcher.

```
var matcher = language.NewMatcher([]language.Tag{
    language.English,
    language.MustParse("ru-RU"),
    language.Russian,
})
```

when you pass in a region and it's not in your matcher it defaults to [ZZ](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language#Region.String) and you hit this [code](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/language/match.go#L114) in the language package.

```
    } else if r := w.RegionID.String(); len(r) == 2 {
        // TODO: also filter macro and deprecated.
        tt, _ = tt.SetTypeForKey("rg", strings.ToLower(r)+"zzzz")
    }
```

If you only want to get the language you can get use the `Base` method from the returned matched tag

```
matched, _, _ := matcher.Match(tag)
base, _ := matched.Base();
fmt.Println(base.String()) // will only print the language
```

using `base.String()` will print `ru` for all of the language headers you provided.